# Integral as an increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $a,b,p$ be any positive real numbers with $a\geq b.$ Then it appears that
$f(x)=\int_0^{2\pi}|a+e^{i\theta}bx|^pd\theta$ is an increasing function on $(0,1).$ May I know how to establish this?

Comment: this is a general result and holds for any $a,b$ complex actually since the function $h(z)=a+bz$ is analytic for $|z|<1$ so $h_p(z)=|h(z)|^p$ is subharmonic in $|z| <1$ so in particular for any $p>0$ one has that $\int_0^{2\pi}h_p(re^{i \theta})d\theta$ increases in $r$ and it actually is also a convex function of $\log r$

Comment: great, thank you

Comment: @Conrad: Why don't you post that as an answer?